# Reading the same line from two different txt files

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, readline

I have data in 2 different txt files that I need data from both (data files are only 630 lines long but I would rather find a way to read the same line than just copy and paste the appropriate column over to one file). The two files have an identical number of lines, and are in the same order

here is the code i'm currently trying to use:

```
import numpy as np
class Source:
    def __init__(self, ra, dec, dist, knAPPMag, SGRB, incl, fif_area):
        self.ra = ra
        self.dec = dec
        self.dist = dist
        self.knAPPMag = knAPPMag
        self.SGRB = SGRB
        self.incl = incl
        self.fif_area = fif_area
def read_dat(data, data2):
    sources = {}
    count = 0
    for line in data:
        if line.startswith('#'):
            continue
        cols = line.split()
        ra = float(cols[3])
        dec = float(cols[4])
        dist = (float(cols[8]))*10e6
        incl = float(cols[5])
        for line2 in data2:
            if line2.startswith('#'):
                continue
            if line == line2:
                cols2 = line2.split()
                fif_area = float(cols2[8])

                knABMag = np.random.uniform(-13, -16)
                knAPPMag = 5*((np.log10(dist)) - 1 ) + knABMag

                SGRB_iso = np.random.uniform(1e+49, 1e+53) 
                dist_m = dist*3.08567758e+16 
                SGRB = SGRB_iso/(dist_m**2)

                name = 'src%05d' % count
                sources[name] = Source(ra, dec, dist, knAPPMag, SGRB, incl, fif_area)
                count=count+1



    return (sources)
```

I want to create a dictionary with entries from both, but when I try, I get an empty dictionary (with the code above)
other things I've tried are:
1) simply running the line2 loop outside of the line loop which leaves me with 630 pretty much empty dictionaries, and 2) taking out the line2 == line loop I'm returned with 396900 dictionary entries

I'm guessing the solution to this problem isn't too complex, I'm just fairly new to python
Cheers,
Jake

Comment: You have a question problem and a logic problem.  The question problem is that you present code irrelevant to your question.  The logic problem is that if `line==line2` then `line2` will not have a column not in `line`.  Btw, you might want to look at `np.loadtxt`.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response!  I've fixed it, but probably the long way round. Simply created a separate function to read that column and add it to the dictionary in another script

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably do something like:

```
from itertools import izip_longest as izipl

def read_pair(fna, fnb):
    lines = {}
    with open(fna, 'r') as fa:
        with open(fnb, 'r') as fb:
            for (i,(la,lb)) in enumerate(izipl(fa, fb)):
                lines[i] = [la, lb]
    return lines

lines = read_pair('file_a.txt', 'file_b.txt')
```

`lines` will be a dictionary with integer indices corresponding to the line number.  The values of the dictionary will be a 2-element list, the first element being the line from file_a.txt and the second element being the line from file_b.txt.